# Display issue on remote machine using GDM X11

Tags: ssh, video, remote-desktop, gdm

I am remotely logging into an Ubuntu machine through SSH(MobaXterm) using Gnome desktop remote environment from my Windows PC. I am having trouble with one of our video applications in displaying video.

Later I tried VLC as well. I could see a local file playing, but the vlc display screen is all black and there is no video.

I tried several things suggested for problems similar to this, but nothing worked.

Things I have tried:

```
export DISPLAY=:0 in bashrc
```

I observed that with this change the Video applications and VLC if instantiated from terminal from SSH session, the application windows are opening on the actual remote ubuntu machine. Hence I reverted this.

Added the following code to ~/.profile (suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display)):

```
case $DISPLAY:$XAUTHORITY in
  :*:?*)
    # DISPLAY is set and points to a local display, and XAUTHORITY is
    # set, so merge the contents of `$XAUTHORITY` into ~/.Xauthority.
    XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority xauth merge "$XAUTHORITY";;
esac
```

added the following line to /etc/ssh/sshd_config :

```
X11UseLocalHost yes
```

But none of these worked. Can someone help me on this one?

Comment: Can anyone help me on this. I am really stuck with this display problem